# SD card files encryption API

Tags: android, encryption, filesystems, android-sdcard

I would like if someone could tell me a way to make folder on the SD card to be hidden/invisible/encrypted when the device connected to usb storage mode / inner file browsing app on the device.
I need also the ability to access this files from my android application (only to read them if it makes any different..)

I know about some file encryption apps like SecretVault pro, but apps like this don't have API for developers, which allow to control the encrypted/decrepited  state progrematically.

Comment: If files are "yours" (i.e. you put them to the SD card), then you need to encrypt them when they are put to the SD and decrypt them in your application when they are needed. If files are not yours, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: the files are "mine".  please tell me how to encrypt/decrepit :)

Comment: Java has very easy to use built in encrypting methods, but they take up precious time.
For example a 188Kb jpg on a Nexus one would take:
Encode: 750ms
Decode 550ms so encryption will be a heavy process for large files

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
 public byte[] keyGen() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGenerator.init(192);
    return keyGenerator.generateKey().getEncoded();
 }
```

you need to store key in your app

```
     public byte[] encript(byte[] dataToEncrypt, byte[] key)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    //I'm using AES encription
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
    return c.doFinal(dataToEncrypt);
    }

    public byte[] decript(byte[] encryptedData, byte[] key)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
    return c.doFinal(encryptedData);
    }
```

Comment: it's working.  though it's not the perfect solution for me, because I need to deal with 1-2GB of content each time the application launched.

Comment: Java has very easy to use built in encrypting methods, but they take up precious time.
For example a 188Kb jpg on a Nexus one would take:
Encode: 750ms
Decode 550ms so encryption will be a heavy process for large files